# Solving $|f(x)| > g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is not a constant and separately, $|f(x)| < g(x)$

Tags: inequality

I know that we can solve using the method shown in http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/inequalities/ineq03/ineq03a5.html , but I am wondering...

> **Question:** Is there anything wrong with simply writing
>
> $|f(x)| > g(x)$ implies
>
> $f(x) > g(x)$ or  $f(x) < -g(x)$?

In other words, simply writing:

$2x-5>x+1$ (without "and $x \geq \frac52$")   or  $2x-5<-x-1$ (without "and $x<\frac52$")

$x>6$              or  $x<\frac43$

---

Similarly,

$|f(x)| < g(x)$ implies

$-g(x) < f(x) < g(x)$  which is

$-g(x) < f(x)$  and $f(x) < g(x)$ .

In other words, $|2x-5|<x+1$ simply implies:

$2x-5<x+1$ (without "and $x \geq \frac52$")   and $2x-5>-x-1$ (without "and $x<\frac52$")

$x<6$              and $x>\frac43\\
\frac43<x<6$

---

It works even for each of the following:

1) $|(x-2)(x-6)| < 0.5x + 1.5$

2) $|(x-2)(x-6)| > 0.5x + 1.5$

but I am not sure if this method works for any expressions for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and I cannot find any source that solves using this method, inequalities of this kind where $g(x)$ is not a constant.

Comment: Yes, $|u|>v$ is equivalent to [$u>v$ or $u<-v$]. When $v\geqslant0$, this is routinely used, but the equivalence also holds when $v<0$ (although it might not be so frequently used) since then, $|u|>v$ and [$u>v$ or $u<-v$] are both true for every $u$. (Asking for sources is rather bizarre here, I think, one can just *look at the thing*...)

Comment: @Did. =D I see. Thanks a lot!